# How can I add multiple destinations in new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Just been on the new Google Maps (the online, desktop browser based, [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/preview?hl=en#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d6202045!2d-2.3278149!3d52.8382004)), and did a route planner from A to B. However, I want to add in a pickup along the way (just like could be done in the [classic maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=Birmingham,+UK&daddr=Peterborough,+UK+to%3aLondon,+UK&hl=en&sll=52.8382,-2.327815&sspn=11.492225,28.54248&geocode=FWPgIAMdnyfj_ylzcUEbLZRwSDGYee6u8P6Byg%3BFZolIgMdblT8_ykFRqrMfQfYRzHVjW3Z4S3-rg%3BFa7_EQMd8Cv-_yl13iGvC6DYRzGZKtXdWjqWUg&mra=ls&t=m&z=9)). How can I do this?

As an example, [here is a route from Birmingham to London](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/preview#!data=!4m23!3m22!1m5!1sBirmingham,+West+Midlands,+UK!2s0x4870942d1b417173:0xca81fef0aeee7998!3m2!3d52.486243!4d-1.890401!1m5!1sLondon,+UK!2s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!3m2!3d51.5112139!4d-0.1198244!2e0!3m8!1m3!1d789988!2d-1.0090922!3d52.0083092!3m2!1i1680!2i965!4f13.1&fid=0), where:

```
A = Birmingham
B = London
```

How can I make it so for example:

```
A = Birmingham (start point)
B = Peterborough (pickup point)
C = London (end point)
```

Comment: It depends on what type of transportation you are selecting, is not currently available for all of them: [see this page](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144339?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now possible.

> Whether you’re running weekend errands or planning a cross-country tour, you can plot multiple destinations for your trip with ease – now available for driving, walking and biking directions. **Once you’ve chosen a starting point, click '+' and add stops to your route by typing in the search box or clicking on the map.**

[Source](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2013/10/hit-road-with-new-google-maps-preview.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no + there right now -- there is "Add destination", but once I have added a third destination I don't see how to populate it by clicking on the map.

Comment: And now there is nothing. He giveth, and he taketh away.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple.

What you need to do is follow steps that are mentioned below for adding multiple destinations....

From point A to Point B - add the destinations and if needed swap the destinations by dragging the "O" with either **mouse+left click hold**  or the **left button+ curser hold** and moving.

Once you add the destinations hit anywhere or hit find route  or **list all steps** for interactive map..

Now to add destination, you can not do on the browser since there is no "+" sign there anymore once you already have activated the route. To add further, go to the map layout in the right pane and click on **full map view**....

Once you click on the full map view, the **route option** with  a "+" will come again in the map browser window. Add the destination and hit **list all steps**. There you go...

Thanks and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Just click and hold the letter label, starting destination `A`, click the actual `A` and hold and drag to where you want it in the list of stops.
It's slow to move, so be patient!

Answer (score 1):

Or after you have added your starting and end point instead of using the "Car" as your method of travel, switch it to "Walking" and the plus sign shows up, put in all your destination, rearrange them whatever you need to do, then switch it back to Car and now you have all your stop points with actual addresses and estimated travel time.

Works for me like a charm, just had to do it today.

Comment: Heh, that worked. Google software is such maldesigned crap.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply start out by getting directions from your departure point to your first destination.

   [image: Step 1]
2. Click the ***+*** beneath your travel points, then enter your third destination.

   [image: Step 2]
3. You can continue for as many destinations as you need, up to **10 maximum**.

   [image: Step 3]

   [image: Done]

Another nice feature is if you get some of your steps out of order, you can drag the circle to the left of the destination in the list up our down to get it in the right spot.

Here's a link to a set of directions using your sample cities: [Birmingham → Peterborough → London](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Birmingham,+West+Midlands,+UK/Peterborough,+UK/London,+United+Kingdom/@52.0365713,-1.9553723,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m20!4m19!1m5!1m1!1s0x4870942d1b417173:0xca81fef0aeee7998!2m2!1d-1.890401!2d52.486243!1m5!1m1!1s0x47d8077dccaa4605:0xaefe2de1d96d8dd5!2m2!1d-0.2405299!2d52.5694985!1m5!1m1!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!2m2!1d-0.1277583!2d51.5073509!3e0)

(This assumes that your country has the latest version of Google Maps and that they have enough data in your country to support this. You'll also need a modern browser. I used Chrome to create these screen shots.)

Note also that this only seems to work for driving, walking, and biking directions. It doesn't work for flights or mass transit.